# Can't upload project to PPA using Quickly

Tags: python, application-development, ppa, launchpad, quickly

I can't get Quickly to upload my project into my PPA. I've set up my PGP key and used it so sign the code of conduct, and the PPA exists. I don't know what other usefull information I can supply.

```
robin@RobinJ:~/Ubuntu One/Python/gtkreddit$ quickly share --ppa robinj/gtkredditGet Launchpad Settings
Launchpad connection is ok
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on configuration file `/home/robin/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: WARNING: unsafe enclosing directory permissions on configuration file `/home/robin/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on configuration file `/home/robin/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: WARNING: unsafe enclosing directory permissions on configuration file `/home/robin/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/share.py", line 138, in <module>
    license.licensing()
  File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/license.py", line 284, in licensing
    {'translatable': 'yes'})
  File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/internal/quicklyutils.py", line 166, in change_xml_elem
    xml_tree.find(parent_node).insert(0, new_node)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'
ERROR: share command failed
Aborting
```

I reported this as a bug on Launchpad, because I assume that it is a bug. If you know a quick workaround, please let me know.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/quickly/+bug/1018138

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPG doesn't like to run if your keys and configurations don't have the right permissions.  Specifically it doesn't like other users being able to read them.  So try running: `chmod 600 /home/robin/.gnupg/gpg.conf` and trying again.  If you get the same error, but from another file in `/home/robin/.gnupg/`, do the same `chmod 600` on that as well.

Comment: Hmm, seems like it wasn't a good idea to `chmod` my whole home directory `777` >.< Now I get this; http://paste.ubuntu.com/1061286/

Comment: Er... `bash: cd: .gnupg/: Permission denied`

Comment: Permissions for the directory; `drw-------+  2 robin robin     4096 Jun 26 20:46 .gnupg`

Comment: I gave the directory execution permissions as you suggested on IRC, which got rid of the permissions issues. The rest of the issues are still standing though. http://paste.ubuntu.com/1061314/

Comment: Have you run "quickly license" yet?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1061436/